# JQuery ajax query fails very silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read similar questions with similar problems but every advice I read seems to be inefficient for me. Here is the ajax call (I am using Jquery 1.9.1):

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
 alert( "AJAX ERROR" );
});

$.post( "/lists/complete", { itemID:id }, function(answer) {
  alert("SUCCESS");
}, "text" ).fail( function() {
  alert("ERROR");
}).always( function() { 
  alert("DONE");
});
```

On the server side the request is received as expected. If I monitor the server response on the client side (using Firebug), I can see that the server sends the 200 response along with the correct data in the body. However, no alert is never triggered !

What can I do to understand the issue ? I must add that I have very little experience with JS and with Jquery...

Comment: Running only the code you posted it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKvH/. What are you doing after the `$.post`?  I suspect there's a javascript error somewhere.

Comment: Are you returning invalid JSON?

Comment: @MichaelKunst After th `$.post` I do nothing. And firebug doesn't report any error in the js...

Comment: @epascarello I don't return json but plain text. I passed the corresponding datatype correctly (at least I think) and the response header is text plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also not a fan of jquery post. I prefer using $.ajax. However it is recommended to chain done, fail and always.

```
$.ajax({
  url: ' yoururl ',
  type: 'POST',
 // dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
  console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **Deprecation Notice:** The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Same problem (as described in the question)

Comment: are the console.log methods in the callbacks firing? Can you set up a jsfiddle to show us the bug? Try the ajax call in a separate file (without any other code) and see if that is working. you'll have to try and pin point your problem because there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: what happens if you visit '/lists/complete' through the browser? are you getting the expected response? Are you using an MVC architecture?

Comment: It seems to work, I was expecting for an alert to pop up, but then I noticed that your solution was logging to the console. I also discovered that console logging does not appear in firebug window, but it does on firefox webdev console. Thanks.

Comment: firebug has a console too. It's the first tab in firebug. console.log makes debugging easier because your script won't get paused for an annoying alert. https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Answer (score 0):

I v never been a fan of the $.post i rather use the full ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/lists/complete',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
    alert("SUCCESS");
  },
  error: function(xhr, type, exception) { 
    // if ajax fails display error alert
    alert("ajax error response type "+type);
  }
});
```

Give this a shot and let me know if the alerts go off.
If this doesn't work out, open up the console (firebug...) and go to the network tab, clear it and send your request.

Click on the request and check the headers and response if they are normal.

Comment: Feel the same about the `$.post` method. Using `$.ajax`, or actually, providing a nice object as an argument is much cleaner, and you don't have to worry about argument placement.

Comment: Same problem (as described in the question)

Comment: @paradigmatic what does the response in the console's network tab show ?

Comment: @paradigmatic ok click on that on it will open up an interface where you can see the response.